# make all text fields in parent document of iframe, read only using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
    parent.document.getElementById('')
```

I am using above code to manipulate elements individually in parent document.
but i want to select all text field of parent document in one call and make them readonly. Because there are more than 70 fields and setting their properties one by one will be a long code.

```
 window.parent.$("form input:text").setAttribute("readOnly","true");
```

and

```
 $(":text").parent().setAttribute("readOnly","true");
```

I have tried both of these above codes but nothing worked.

Comment: tell me that iframe is under the same domain ?

Comment: yes the iframe is under the same domain. @ arclite

Comment: ok i've added some code that must work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("form input:text").prop( "readonly", true );
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mCCz9/)

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for you

```
window.parent.$("form input[type=text]").setAttribute("readOnly","true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.attr('readonly','readonly');`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qU599/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you,

```
$(':text').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
window.parent.$("form input:text").attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("form input:text").attr('readonly',true);
```

or

```
$("iframe").contents().find("form input[type=text]").attr('readonly',true);
```